# Linking with g++ needs explicit location of some libraries

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I use g++ for linking my object files, but why do I need to tell g++ explicitly where the libraries are, if they are all in `/usr/lib/`?
I call it that way:

```
g++ -o "rsb_sending" ./rsb_sending.o -L/usr/lib \
                      -l:librsbts.so -l:librsbsimplebuffer.so \
                      -l:librsb.so.0.9 -l:librsc0.9.so -l:libboost_system.so
```

If I just call

```
g++ -o "rsb_sending" ./rsb_sending.o
```

it won't link. What am I missing here, if even `ldonfig -p` prints out alle the named libraries?

THX

Comment: Humm, did you tried -lbrsbts -lrsbsimplebuffer -lrsb -lrsc0 -lboost_system ?

Comment: You always have to explicitly list all linked libraries, `g++ -o "rsb_sending" ./rsb_sending.o` won't do the trick. You can't expect the linker to guess what libraries are required. libstd is one exception, because no program can be created without it. Demonofnight's solution should do the trick.

Comment: Ah ok, now I got it. But what demonofnight wrote is quite the same, not actually a trick, isn't it?

Comment: @Tik0 it's not the same, semantics of linking by namespec and filename differ. See `man ld`